# Transforming Geometry to BufferGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js, buffer-geometry

As I understand it, Geometry stores a javascript object structure of the vertices and faces and BufferGeometry just stores the raw gl data via Float32Arrays, etc.

Is there any way to turn standard Geometry into BufferGeometry, which is a lot more memory compact with less objects? For example if I create a new SphereGeometry, is there a way to easily transform that to a BufferGeometry?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**This answer only applies to versions of three.js prior to r.125.**

The Legacy `Geometry` class has been removed.

---

```js
var bufferGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry( geometry );
```

three.js r.124

Comment: I just tried using this (brand spanking new, huh) but the faces don't port over. I've tried setting the nonexistant faces property on the buffer geometry to that on the old geometry, but no dice.

Comment: Works for me. Quad faces are not supported in r.60, only tris. Step through the code with the debugger. You can probably figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Ah, yeah I saw that and made something based on that code. Thanks! Ported my spheres to BufferGeometry: http://i.imgur.com/UCB1f61.png

Comment: After converting your geometry to a buffergeometry, is there a way to save it and load it later from a file? Currently I'm loading a large model from a .ply and I'm looking for a performance improvement.

Comment: @foobarbecue You need to make a new post if you have a question.

Comment: I seems that `fromGeometry()` is no longer a method of [`BufferGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=buffergeo#api/en/core/BufferGeometry).