# Three js buffergeometry for spheres

Tags: javascript, three.js, buffer-geometry

Im trying to make a three js document which shows lots of spherical objects, the quickest way to do this is by using buffergeometry. From this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262868/transforming-geometry-to-buffergeometry) I learned that I could convert normal geometry into buffergeometry using:

```
    var sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 4, 0.05, 0.025 );
    var geometry = THREE.BufferGeometryUtils.fromGeometry( sphere );
```

But this does not seem to work for me, the rest of the code that creates the object reads:

```
    var positions = new Float32Array( x_GAMA.length * 3 );


    for ( var i = 0; i < x_GAMA.length; i += 1 ) {

                // positions

                positions[ 3*i ]     =  x_GAMA[i]*10000;
                positions[ 3*i + 1 ] =  y_GAMA[i]*10000;
                positions[ 3*i + 2 ] =  z_GAMA[i]*10000;



            }
    geometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( positions, 3 ) );

    var material = new THREE.PointCloudMaterial( {size:1,color:0x999999}  );

    geometry.computeBoundingSphere();

    particleSystem = new THREE.PointCloud( geometry, material );


    scene.add( particleSystem );
```

It works fine if I  use `var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();` but this creates squares which I do not want. Anyone have any idea why this does not seem to work? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In **Three.js r71** you can create Sphere Buffer Geometry like this:

```
var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 4, 3, 2 );
var bufferSphereGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry( sphereGeometry );
```

In **r72 dev** you can do ít straightforward like this:

```
// constructor: radius, widthSegments, heightSegments, phiStart, phiLength, thetaStart, thetaLength
var sphereGeo = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry( 4, 3, 2 ); //r72
```