# three.js r74 BufferGeometry Sphere Instead of Squares

Tags: javascript, three.js, buffer-geometry

I have the following code:

```
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry(4, 4, 4);
var length = parsedData.length;
var positions = new Float32Array(length * 3);
var colors = new Float32Array(length * 3);

var color = new THREE.Color();

var i = 0;
for (i; i < length * 3; i += 3) {
    var index = Math.floor(i / 3);
    positions[i] = parsedData[index].vector.x;
    positions[i + 1] = parsedData[index].vector.y;
    positions[i + 2] = parsedData[index].vector.z;

    color.setHex(parsedData[index].color);
    colors[i] = color.r;
    colors[i + 1] = color.g;
    colors[i + 2] = color.b;
}

geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, 3));
geometry.addAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(colors, 3));

var material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors});
var particleSystem = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
scene.add(particleSystem);
render();
```

Which will render cubes quickly and fine, but I need spheres. Could anyone explain to me how that works with Revision 74? I have found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491068/three-js-buffergeometry-for-spheres), however it isn't working anymore.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean [this](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_points_billboards.html). Or perhaps [this](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_points_billboards_colors.html)?

Comment: Hey @WestLangley, either might work. But this line, `sprite = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "textures/sprites/ball.png" );` doesn't work in r74. Also, why do I need to load an image of a ball? How do I make that?

Comment: I talked with a colleague today, let me try some stuff I will let you know what I decide.

Comment: `THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "textures/sprites/ball.png" );` is being deprecated (it does work). None of this is intuitive to use, it's very frustrating.

Comment: Learning something new is hard work.